# Caret position when centering with flexbox in contenteditable

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, flexbox, contenteditable

Tested on OSX Chrome 45, `align-items: center;` is working for content, but if you click into the empty editable below, the caret position is not centered until you start typing.

Is the only way to fix this with top/bottom balanced padding or is there a way of getting this to work without pixel shifting? Thanks

```css
[contenteditable="true"] {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 46px;
}

[contenteditable="true"]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
<div contenteditable="true">content is centered, but caret isn't</div>
```

Comment: `line-height` would be a better option than `padding`. I don't know of a way to do this without fixed pixel positioning though.

Answer (score 1):

As James Donnelly said in the comment, you can try adding line-height to your rules, eg:

```css
[contenteditable="true"] {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 46px;
    line-height: 46px;
}
```

However I'd actually probably go with `padding` instead. Adding the `min-height` to your `contenteditable` element is what's causing the issues between the cursor and the inputted value. Take away the `min-height`, and the problem is solved. Then your problem becomes "How do I add an even amount of space around this `contenteditable` element?" - and that's exactly what padding is for :)

So perhaps something more like:

```css
[contenteditable="true"] {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px 0;
}
```

Depends on what exactly you're trying to implement though, and whether you really need to fix the height of the div.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this effect the element's line-height has to be set to the same pixel value of the element's height. Then on :focus you can change it to a normal line-height. See the snippet below.

```css
[contenteditable="true"] {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 46px;
    line-height:46px;
}

[contenteditable="true"]:focus {
    outline: none;
}

[contenteditable="true"]:focus:not(:empty) {
    line-height:normal;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
<div contenteditable="true">content is centered, but caret isn't</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me. In Chrome the cursor was wrongly placed off-center on the vertical axis.

Interestingly this only works with pixels or rem units, but not with percentage or unit less line-heights.

In my case I want the caret to have the height of the capital letter (a pre-defined unit less value e.g. 0.7)

[contenteditable="true"]:empty {
  line-height: calc(var(--font-size) * var(--capital-letter-height));
}

Answer (score 0):

just put `line-height: 150%` for your contenteditable div

**but** if you want to set `font-size`, you should Note that you should compute `line-height` in proportion with `font-size` to make the caret vertically center

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use padding instead of min-height and line-height. If it's not important to fix the height of that div.
Because of padding it also looks clean.

```css
[contenteditable="true"] {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px;
}
```