# text-align center not working for empty contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, dom-events

I have a div with `contenteditable="true"` and `resize: both` attributes which has centered text via flexbox

```
.edit-area {      
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: rgba(206, 206, 206, 0.5);
      border: 0.1rem solid gray;
      resize: both;
      overflow: hidden;
}
```

the problem is that when you focus the div and it is empty the caret position is on left top corner
[image]

and only when you type 1 character the caret jumps to the center
[image]

i've done some research and found answers like these:
[Caret position when centering with flexbox in contenteditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905957/caret-position-when-centering-with-flexbox-in-contenteditable)
[Centering the placeholder caret in contentEditable element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29288975/centering-the-placeholder-caret-in-contenteditable-element)

`text-align:center` on `:empty` selector works for horizontal centering,
but for the vertical align the problem remains, fixes with `line-height = initial height` on `:empty` selector wont work in my case because this div can be resized, is there any ways to set caret on the center programmatically with onFocus event, or with some other css tricks?

with help of @Spectric answer here is the solution that i end up with:

```
const FILLCHARACTER = String.fromCharCode(8203);

node
  .on("input", textInputHandler)
  .on("keydown", textKeyDownHandler);

  const textInputHandler = () => {
    const nodeDOM = d3.select(textNode.current).node();
    if (nodeDOM.innerText.toString().length == 0) {
      nodeDOM.innerHTML = FILLCHARACTER;
    }
  };

  const textKeyDownHandler = (event) => {
    if (event.key == "Backspace") {
      const selectionText = window.getSelection().toString();
      const selectionLength = selectionText.length;
      const currentTextLength = textValue.current.length;
      if (
        selectionLength === currentTextLength ||
        (selectionLength === 1 &&
          (/\u200B/g.test(selectionText) ||
            selectionText.indexOf(FILLCHARACTER) !== -1))
      ) {
        d3.select(textNode.current).node().innerHTML = FILLCHARACTER;
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: try this. .edit-area{      
      position: fixed;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: rgba(206, 206, 206, 0.5);
      border: 0.1rem solid gray;
      resize: both;
      overflow: hidden;  
}

Comment: i suggest using flex if you have multiple containers in the event of having a parent container and a direct child elements

Comment: @WeyersdeLange i am using flex because i need to center text on contenteditable div, if  there are any other ways to do it i would like to try them just let me know how, also didn't get the idea behind position:fixed(didn't work btw).

Comment: did you find a non-hackish solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JavaScript you can insert a space ('`&nbsp;`') when you detect the contenteditable is empty. This pushes the caret position to the center.

```js
document.querySelector('.edit-area').addEventListener("input", function() {
  if (this.innerText.toString().length == 0) {
    this.innerHTML= '&nbsp;';
  }
})
```

```css
.edit-area {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(206, 206, 206, 0.5);
  border: 0.1rem solid gray;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="edit-area" contenteditable>
&nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: thats a way to go but i would recommend to also add a keydown handler and check for backspace usage and use &#8203 instead of space character

Comment: this is such a hackish solution. is there really no other way still?

Comment: @oldboy it's not very elegant, but it's not *terrible* either. If you're sending this data to the server you could just trim it (like you would normally do).

Comment: well u could change the event and only automatically input a space if its empty on blur, but still there must be a better or proper way nowadays